# Ruby DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using the old router DSL which will be removed in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3 and at the moment I'm writing tests for my application. 
I get this weird deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using the old router DSL which will be removed in Rails 3.1. Please check how to update your routes file at: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/jeljer/Dropbox/webCMS/config/environment.rb:6)
```

Of course my routes file is this:

```
WebCMS::Application.routes.draw do
  #...
end
```

but no luck. If I look at the place what it is pointing to in my enviroment.rb:

```
WebCMS::Application.initialize!
```

I did a gem cleanup without any luck.
Does anybody have an idea?

ps. I'm using RVM with Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Have you checked that its not some plugin adding old style routes? Hmm.. maybe the path would be different then.

Comment: gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.0.pre'
gem 'capistrano'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'infinity_test'
end

group :production do
  gem 'ruby-mysql'
end

Comment: Hmm don't think so.. i have no "weird" gems in my gem file.

Comment: What is the contents of your routes file?

Comment: here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/763258

Comment: Ok so i removed everything in my routes file and run it again! It is defenately NOT in the routes file! I really can't figure out why nobody else has this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the routes file you posted I get no such error. Perhaps it's a gem or a plugin that you're using that's giving you this?

I did a Rails 3 upgrade recently and an old version of the `declarative_authorization` gem gave me this error.

Comment: ah yes that could be! But how do i figure that out? My app is in production and i has been working fine! it is just the deprecation warning when running tests (which is annoying :P) here is my gem list https://gist.github.com/764679 I don't use very unusual gems

Comment: @user297221: It's the ckeditor gem: https://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Comment: Ok for the people who als have this problem here the github fork: https://github.com/heldopslippers/rails-ckeditor

Comment: if you want to use it, do this in your gem file and run bundle install: gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'git@github.com:heldopslippers/rails-ckeditor.git'

Comment: Hey, so I am facing same issue.. and I am very new to ruby/rails.. from this thread what I got is that it is some kind of version problem.. and I have to run this command inside my rails app folder...

command is this ***** bundle install: gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'git@github.com:heldopslippers/rails-ckeditor.git' ***** but this is giving me error that No such directory exists... my question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780984/rails-error-you-are-using-the-old-router-dsl-which-has-been-removed-in-rails-3?noredirect=1#comment63029386_37780984

Answer (score 4):

It usually happens when you pass the |map| parameter ([see this post](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/08/rails-3-you-are-using-the-old-router-dsl/)).
Make sure you're not passing the parameter to the block.

Comment: I am sorry! But as i stated in my post i don't.. see my routes file https://gist.github.com/763258 (or do you mean somewhere else ?)